# nouns derived from separable verbs

Tags: noun, separable-verb

I am looking for a list of German nouns derived from separable verbs. For example:

- *abholen*: Abholung
- *anfangen*: Anfang
- *abnehmen*: Abnahme

Does anything like this exist? Do these nouns have a specific name? I've searched around but so far came up empty handed. Danke im Voraus!

Comment: Pretty much every separable verb can be turned into at least one noun. I doubt such lists exist.

Comment: Nobody would do such a list. A complementary reason to Jan's comment is that precisely the interesting list would be, if any, for the *non-separable* verbs. The separable are secondary, sort of.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want to limit this to separable verbs? Because it works the same way for non-separable verbs.

The -ung-Form is used to name the result of an action, sometimes a recurring action (as in *Leitung* or *Forschung*.)

> rechnen (to calculate) → Rechnung (bill)
>
> leiten (to manage, conduct) → Leitung (management, wire, pipeline)
>
> forschen (to research) → Forschung (research)

Nouns ending in -e instead of -ung are not made from the verb but vice-versa, or they just share the same root.

> liegen (to lie, to couch) ←→ Liege (couch)
>
> spitzen (to sharpen) ←→ Spitze (tip)

They often have a totally different meaning.

> ahnen (to forebode) → Ahnung (presentiment)
>
> ahnen (to forebode) ←|→ Ahne (ancestor)
>
> rollen (to roll) ←→ Rolle (roll, but also **role !**)

Another list can be made for people or things who/which do something. Still no separable verb required.

> rechnen (to calculate) → Rechner (computer, calculator)
>
> leiten (to manage, conduct) → Leiter (manager, conductor)
>
> forschen (to research) → Forscher, Forscherin (researcher)

And another list of nouns prefixed with Ge- denote a tool used to do the action or an alternative result when the -ung-form means something different or is nonexistant for non-obvious reasons.

> fahren (to drive) → Gefährt (vehicle)
>
> fühlen (to feel) → Gefühl (feeling) (*Fühlung* means *contact*)
>
> backen (to bake) → Gebäck (pastry) (<s>Backung</s> is nonexistant)
>
> züchten (to breed) → Gezücht (brood) (*Züchtung* means the action of *breeding*, today it's used for *brood*, too)