# Why are there differences in endings of nouns derived from verbs? How do I know which ending to use?

Tags: suffix, nominalization

This question nouns refers to nouns that are forms of verbs in English, or their equivalents in German.

Some examples are:

> abholen: Abholung 
>   anfangen: Anfang 
>   aufnehmen: Aufnahme

The first one ends with -ung, and the second one ends with -ng, using its own "a," rather than a "u," as a vowel. That much I understand.

But the third ending "nahme," deviates significantly from the other two. If it followed the "pattern," it would be something like "aufnehmung," or "aufneng," but that's not the case.

Why is that? Is that for purposes of "assimilation?" Could it have to do with the "h" in "nehmen?" Is that the only deviation, or are there others that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Not all nouns that have similar forms of verbs have been derived from them. Sometimes, the verb may have been derived from the noun or the noun and the verb co-evolved in parallel.

Comment: @Jan: That's a good comment. If you could provide some examples of " the verb may have been derived from the noun or the noun and the verb co-evolved in parallel," that would make an excellent answer.

Comment: Here, two links where the derivation fromverbs to nouns is described. There is more than just one rule: http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/V-To-N/Pre+Suffig.html http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/V-To-N/Suffig.html

Comment: Your question could be understood to claim "German has a gerund" (I know you didn't say this). Just to clear this up: No, it hasn't. And you probably shouldn't assume the "-ung" substantiation ending in German is in any way related to the "-ing" gerund ending in English. This might lead you onto wrong tracks.

Comment: Alliteration (Stabreim in German) is something completely different: A group of words that begin with the same consonant, e.g. "**M**anner **m**ag **m**an eben". You probably meant assimilation, which is changing letters to make pronouncing words more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These words are not gerunds, they are nouns.
Verbs can be turned into nouns in several ways. To a certain extent, you will need to simply learn the noun forms by heart, but the various endings tend to carry a certain meaning.
For example

**nouns ending in -ung**
usually express an occurrence or a process
always feminine
verbinden - die Verbindung,
entwickeln - die Entwicklung

**Infinitives with 'das'**
usually express an action
always neuter
lernen - das Lernen,
leben - das Leben

**ending in -ion or -tion**
usually for foreign words
always feminine
diskutieren - die Diskussion,
organisieren - die Organisation

Answer (score 6):

**There is no gerundium in German**. A gerundium is a verb form, while these words you gave are nouns made from verbs or share the same root as a verb.

[I've answered a similar question recently.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/nouns-derived-from-separable-verbs/33285#33285)

Comment: This question was actually inspired by the other one. But mine is, why is the Aufnahme form so different from the other two.  Is there a rule governing the other two that makes Aufnahme an exception? Or is there even a scenario where Aufnahme is considered a more pronounceable form of "Aufnehmung."

Comment: No. *Aufnehmung* doesn't exist. Neither does *Backung* exist nor *Backe* is a form of *backen*. *Aufnahme* isn't a form of the verb but a noun independent from it. It just happens to share the same word stem. There are some general hints how to find out or even make up a noun related to a verb (as I wrote in the other post) with the desired meaning or function but no strict rule you could follow.

Comment: But "Ausnehmung" does exist as a technical term in mechanics, while it's not an "Ausnahme"

Comment: @tofro, typischer wäre aber «Aussparung». Auf den Artikel verweist zumindest der Duden, wenn man nach «Ausnehmung» sucht.

Comment: @iris Stimmt. Aber: Der Duden ist leider keine sehr gute Referenz für technische Fachbegriffe

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment: Not EVERY noun in Germany can be built by just adding an "ung" to it. Already your conclusion regarding your second example is wrong.

If it was the gerund form ,it would be something in the line of "Anfangung".

The rule that every verb has a gerund form that can be derived from its verb by adding "ung" is simply wrong.

Nothing more to say...

Comment: I would guess this is true of "most," probably not all. Perhaps "anfangen/Anfang" is an exception, as you state. Then the question is, what is the exception and what is the rule?

Comment: @Tom Au, I would estimate that the majority of nouns is constructed without adding an "ung". And I think there are several rules how nouns are built, so it is wrong to think of one rule and exceptions.